# Building Houses Evenly in Monopoly

Tags: monopoly

I was playing Monopoly with my friend one day and I had an orange full set AND a red full set. I started to add houses to the sets. However, as soon as I added a second house onto Vine Street/New York (the formation of houses for the oranges and reds were 1-1-2 0-0-0), my friend suddenly told me that I wasn't following the rules of building evenly. According to him, I had to build houses on the reds, i.e. 1-1-1 1-1-1, before I could start on second houses.

> The properties in a color group must be developed evenly, i.e. each house that is built must go on a property in the group with the fewest number of houses on it so far.

This is what the rulebook says about building houses evenly across **a** colour set, however, I couldn't find anything that says that houses had to be built evenly **across** colour sets.

Is what I did against the rules?

Answer (score 5):

You played within the rules. Houses must be built up (and sold off) evenly within a color group, but different color groups can be built up differently without regard to each other.

The section of [the rules you quote](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Monopoly/Official_Rules) is exactly the section that supports your play.

Addendum: not an official source, but this same question came up on boardgamegeek (with the same answer).

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/435348/confuse-about-building-evenly

Answer (score 1):

The rules specify that the build up only applies to the same color group. There is nothing to control what is built on properties of other groups in the rules.

[Houses](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf)

> But
>   you must build evenly, i.e., you cannot erect more than one house on
>   any one property of any color-group until you have built one house on
>   every property of that group. You may then begin on the second row
>   of houses, and so on, up to a limit of four houses to a property. For
>   example, you cannot build three houses on one property if you have
>   only one house on another property of that group.
>   As you build evenly, you must also break down evenly if you sell
>   houses back to the Bank (see SELLING PROPERTY).